# Split an array of strings into two arrays, each with a part of the original string

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, string

I am working with JSON data, and one of the items I want to use is actually two pieces of information formatted together, separated by |.

This is an example of the string that is being returned: "Rocket | Mission".

I have pulled this information into an array for each rocket | mission, so their are 30 items in the array

I have a for loop that generates this array:

```
var names = ["rocket1 | mission1", "rocket2 | mission2", ...];
```

I am trying to separate the items in that array into:

```
var rocket = ["rocket1, rocket2, rocket3, ...];
var mission = ["mission1, mission2, mission3, ...];
```

so that I can loop through and display each rocket and mission separately.

I have tried using `substring(indexOf(" | ") +1);` and `split();` but I keep getting to a point where I need a loop within a loop within a loop.  I am a beginner at javascript and I don't understand the syntax and logic well enough to figure out how and where to apply those methods to get what I want.

Hope this makes sense Thanks for your help!

Comment: Create 2 empty arrays outside your loop, `rocket` and `mission`. Then create the loop that iterates `names`. Inside that loop, grab the current item, and use `.split()` to split it on the `" | "`. Then `.push()` the `0` index of the `split` result into the `rocket` array, and the `1` index into the `mission` array.

Comment: Are all the rockets different, (same question for missions), or are only the combinations unique? Do you only need duplicates to be removed somewhere?

Comment: ...an alternative storage structure would be to map `names` to an array of objects, each of which holds a `mission` and a `rocket`.

Comment: The rockets may be duplicated, but each mission is different, and each combination is unique and paired together.  The script will eventually pull information about the next 30 upcoming rocket launches, then display the rocket name and mission for each launch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like squint said in the comments, you're going to want to create the two arrays and then loop through the original array, splitting it into the two new arrays

```
var rocket = [];
var mission = [];

for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
    var temp = names[i].split(" | ");
    rocket.push(temp[0]);
    mission.push(temp[1]);
}
```

Comment: This gives me a names.split is not a function error in the console.

Comment: @ncox85: Superhq just forgot to type the index.

Comment: Ah, yes.  I added that at first too, but I still got an error.  Turns out it worked fine, but I was getting an error when I printed to the page because my variable names changed!  This works exactly how I wanted it to!

Answer (score 3):

Use [**split**](https://www.google.com/?ion=1&espv=2#q=javascript%20split) while taking a *functional* approach with **[forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)**

```js
let names = ["rocket1 | mission1", "rocket2 | mission2"]

let rocket = []
let mission = []

names.forEach(name => {
  let splat = name.split(' | ')

  rocket.push(splat[0])
  mission.push(splat[1])
  })

console.log(rocket)
console.log(mission)
```

Comment: Is it better to use a for loop or a forEach loop?

Comment: It's basically just preference. @AmmarCSE's solution might be slightly more elegant, but a basic for loop is easier for an average programmer to understand.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `map` together with `split`:

```js
var names = ["rocket1 | mission1", "rocket2 | mission2"];

var rockets = names.map( name => name.split(' | ')[0] );
var missions = names.map( name => name.split(' | ')[1] );

console.log(rockets)
console.log(missions);
```

#### Alternative 2

This uses `reduce` and destructuring to accomplish the task in one cycle. *Functional programming* die-hards may like this one, but it is harder to read for those not accustomed to these compact `reduce` constructs.

```js
var names = ["rocket1 | mission1", "rocket2 | mission2"];

var [rockets, missions] = names.reduce( (pairs, name, i) => 
    ([pairs[0][i], pairs[1][i]] = name.split(' | '), pairs)
, [[], []]);

console.log(rockets);
console.log(missions);
```

Comment: I like your alternative. However, there is the downside of iterating twice through the `names`

Comment: Thanks, I added an other alternative that does not have this drawback.

Comment: Woh! **very, very nice** on this bit `([pairs[0][i], pairs[1][i]] = name.split(' | '), pairs)`. It took me a while to figure out that you were destructuring using the `0` and `1` index from the `split` result and that you were effectively returning `pairs` after the the comma. Dont misunderstand me, I prefer simpleness(which this is not) over complexity, but I definitely learned something new! :-)

Comment: I know what mean. This kind of code is a pleasure to write, but can be a pain to analyse. But then when the light shines, the pleasure is back again :-)